# Makefile errors cpuminer Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: make

cpuminer wont install. At the end of the script I get errors:

```
/home/barv/cpuminer-multi/./compat/jansson/jansson.h:159: undefined reference to `json_object_set_new'
/tmp/ccmWdwtA.ltrans27.ltrans.o: In function `rpc2_job_decode.part.10.lto_priv.371':
/home/barv/cpuminer-multi/util.c:1578: undefined reference to `json_object_get'
/home/barv/cpuminer-multi/util.c:1583: undefined reference to `json_string_value'
/home/barv/cpuminer-multi/util.c:1584: undefined reference to `json_object_get'
/home/barv/cpuminer-multi/util.c:1589: undefined reference to `json_string_value'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Reaping losing child 0xdf7d50 PID 3148 
Makefile:900: recipe for target 'cpuminer' failed
make[2]: *** [cpuminer] Error 1
Removing child 0xdf7d50 PID 3148 from chain.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/barv/cpuminer/gr/cpuminer-multi'
Reaping losing child 0x16e57e0 PID 3129 
Makefile:2530: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
Removing child 0x16e57e0 PID 3129 from chain.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/barv/cpuminer/gr/cpuminer-multi'
Reaping losing child 0x2515710 PID 3128 
Makefile:570: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Removing child 0x2515710 PID 3128 from chain.
```

My guess is that the install script was written for 14.04. What could be wrong here?

Cheers. Barv

Comment: You will need to scroll up to find out why `ld returned 1 exit status` - the fragment you've posted is not sufficient to make a diagnosis

Comment: thx. Meanwhile i started over. I will post updates after next try

Comment: @steeldriver it seems that errors start with json:

Comment: /home/barv/cpuminer-multi/cpu-miner.c:734: undefined reference to `json_object_get'

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was missing `sudo apt-get install libjansson-dev`. After I installed that I re-ran the commands from the readme:

```
./autogen.sh    # only needed if building from git repo
./nomacro.pl    # only needed if building on Mac OS X or with Clang
./configure CFLAGS="*-march=native*" --with-crypto --with-curl
# Use -march=native if building for a single machine
make
```

and it worked. I was using raspbian-stretch lite but it uses apt-get as well